# How do i get MVC working with Dynamics CRM?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using MVC 3 and Dynamics CRM 2011.
IIS 7 on 2008
I placed my app in the ISV folder. 
This application works outside of CRM. 
My controller name is User, siteurl/user does not work
site/user/index does work

it constantly adds default.aspx to the end of the url. I am running in 4.0 integrated mode.

I have removed the default.aspx entry from default document. Though it's fine to hang out on a standard IIS.

Please I am in so much mental pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get it working in a supported way.

- [The ISV directory is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571.aspx) and should not be used anymore. It was never really ment to host complete web applications. It was meant for small apps which run in the context of Dynamics CRM. Instead use a separate website which connects to Dynamics CRM
- Dynamics CRM 2011 has it's own URL-rewriting which extracts the information about the tenant from the requested URI. This will conflict with your app